# Terrible Network Performance in Games

Tags: networking, internet, ping, gaming, packet-loss

For a start, my packet loss is very minimal, around 0.1%, and my ping is 10 ms on average. But when I play games or do something ping-sensitive, I lag so much that it's unplayable (I have the right server selected, and the ping in games is pretty great). My download and upload speeds are great, my PC specs are great, and I don't have a problem anywhere else than in these "speed-sensitive" things. I have a great ISP, and a simple mikrotik setup and I have tried everything.

I run Windows 10.
Do you know any solutions that might help me? Thanks!

Comment: Test your speeds with a website such as https://www.speedtest.net/

Comment: as I said in the post,my speeds are really great and the ping too

Comment: "ping-sensitive" doesn't really mean anything, `ping` is just a tool to determine if a remote system is up. It uses ICMP as a protocol, and as a management protocol ICMP has a very low priority. The target will respond when it has time; everything else takes precedence. If I understand correctly your problem is a lag when you're playing certain games, but regular internet traffic has no issues. That looks like an issue with the game server resources.

Comment: On how many games does this arrive, all of them? And which ones?

Comment: Yes, regular internet traffic is not a problem. And it's all games that are meant to be played in real-time and online.

Comment: Can you give their names?

Comment: See https://www.bufferbloat.net/projects/ & run the tests - also try switching to wired ethernet & repeat the tests.